# Splint doesn't know that library function is freeing memory

Tags: mysql, c, splint

When using MySQL in C you free the memory using the MySQL API, like so:

```
MYSQL* connection = NULL;
connection = mysql_init(NULL);
// Stuff...
mysql_close(connection);
```

But Splint doesn't know that `mysql_close` is in fact freeing memory, so I get this error:

```
Fresh storage connection not released before return
A memory leak has been detected. Storage allocated locally is 
not released before the last reference to it is lost. (Use 
-mustfreefresh to inhibit warning)
```

How do I tell Splint that `mysql_close` is deallocating memory? A special annotation to the `mysql.h` file?

**EDIT**: OK, maybe the `releases *p` annotation, if that can be used in a header file. Will try.

**EDIT 2**: Added `/*@releases *sock@*/` to `mysql.h`, but now get this error:

```
Releases clauses includes *sock of non-dynamically allocated
              type MYSQL
A declaration uses an invalid annotation. (Use -annotationerror to inhibit
warning)
```

This is the signaure of `mysql_close`:

```
void STDCALL mysql_close(/*@notnull@*/ MYSQL *sock) /*@releases *sock@*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that proper annotation would be:

```
void STDCALL mysql_close(/*@special@*/ /*@notnull@*/ MYSQL *sock)
    /*@releases sock@*/;
```

The key, that you have missed is `/*@special@*/` annotation, that is required to "activate" so called state clauses. From Splint's documentation, [7.4 State Clauses](http://www.splint.org/manual/manual.html#_Ref354411787):

> The `/*@special@*/` annotation is used to mark a parameter, global
>   variable, or return value that is described using state clauses.

Comment: Thanks! This is correct, but why must I remove the asterisk from `sock`? As seen above, I actually wrote `/*@releases *sock@*/`. What's the difference?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: The asterisk has different meaning, depending on context. For `MYSQL *sock` it is a fragment of *declarator* (part of declaration), to indicate, that `sock` is a pointer, that may point to `MYSQL` object. Within annotation `*sock` reflects not to pointer itself, but to referenced object **by** that pointer, in other words `*` is *indirection operator* in such context, but pointer is `sock` itself.